# Save deform.FileData schema node as file

Tags: python-3.x, colander, deform

My script is exactly as the [Deform File Upload Widget example](http://deform2demo.repoze.org/file/):

```
@view_config(renderer='templates/form.pt', name='file')
@demonstrate('File Upload Widget')
def file(self):

    class Schema(colander.Schema):
        upload = colander.SchemaNode(
            deform.FileData(),
            widget=deform.widget.FileUploadWidget(tmpstore)
            )

    schema = Schema()
    form = deform.Form(schema, buttons=('submit',))

    return self.render_form(form, success=tmpstore.clear)
```

the captured upload with `test_file.grf` is a [`deform.FileData` schema node](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/deform/en/latest/api.html#deform.FileData) which looks like:

```
>> captured['upload']
{'filename': u'test_file.grf',
 'fp': <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x000000000638A6A0>,
  'mimetype': 'text/plain',
  'preview_url': None,
  'size': -1,
  'uid': '42DXY7DYW3'}
```

**Question**

How to save `deform.FileData` as a file on a specific location?

An attempt is to open and copy the file to location `src` gave a `TypeError`:

```
with open(captured['upload']['fp'], 'r') as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, src)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it simply by binary opening the file:

```
with open(src, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(captured['upload']['fp'].read())
```